# Confusion on the proof of a ring of integers must be a Dedekind Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

In class, we proved the following statement: Let $R$ be a Dedekind Domain with field of fractions $K$. Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension. Then the integral closure $S$ of $R$ in $L$ is a Dedekind Domain. An immediate corollary of this is that any ring of integers is a Dedekind domain. I have some questions about this part of the proof, which I'll outline below. The parts which I don't get are bolded.

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a $K$-basis of $L$. Now we showed that one can take each $x_i \in S$ without loss of generality, which I understand. Now let $\{y_i\}$ be a dual basis of $L$ with respect to $\{x_j\}$, that is, $\{y_i\}$ is a basis for $L$ over $K$ such that $$Tr_{L/K}(x_i, y_j) = \delta_{ij}.$$ Suppose that $\alpha \in S$, with $$\alpha = \sum_{r}a_ry_r$$ with $a_r \in K$. Then, $$\alpha x_j = \sum_{r}a_ry_rx_j.$$ Taking the trace of both sides, we get that $$Tr_{L/K}(\alpha_jx_j) = a_j.$$ $\textbf{Therefore a_j is an element of R}.$

How do we arrive at that conclusion? I know that we can define the trace as the sum of the Galois conjugates, but I don't see why that implies $a_j$ is an element of $R$.

Comment: The trace of $\alpha x_j$ is, up to a sign, the second highest degree coefficient of the minimal polynomial of the multiplication operator. Since $\alpha x_j$ is integral over $R$, all these coefficients are actually in $R$. Details covering this situation can be found in Lemma 5.14, and Props 5.15 & 5.17 in Atiyah and MacDonald's Commutative Algebra. The proof you present here effectively seems exactly like Prop 5.17 from that text, so 5.14 and 5.15 should clear things up. Also for reference, Theorem 9.5 of the same text completes the proof that a ring of integers is Dedekind.

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out in Atiyah MacDonald. This makes sense, but I was wondering if there's any way to get the result from defining the trace as a sum of Galois conjugates?

Comment: Galois conjugates of integral elements are integral (same monic minimal polynomial), so $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}$ sends $S$ to the intersection of $K$ (since it is trace) and the integral closure of $R$ in $K$.  Since $R$ is integrally closed, you get $a_j=\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(\alpha x_j)\in\operatorname{Tr}_{L/K}(S)\subseteq R$.

Comment: Oops, slight typo above, should be integral closure of $R$ in $L$, not $K$.

Comment: This checks out, thanks!